# "Make something out of" or "Make something with"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

So there was a fill in quiz I had to do, and there was a question it says:

> Bill can make a doghouse *_* paper. That's cool.

I filled in 'out of'.

> Bill can make a doghouse **out of** paper.

And my teacher said "No, it's not quite right, it's supposed to be

> Bill can make a doghouse **with** paper.

*out of* and *with* have slightly different meaning."

She provided no further explanation. That made me really confused about it.
Help?

Comment: Hello 341464, your teacher is right: "made out" is a phrasal verb that you cannot use here (concrete case) because it has a different meaning.

Comment: You what?  That's nonsense.  The student's answer is perfectly valid and there's nothing (as far as we can see) in the question to specify the second answer and rule out the first.

Comment: And that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Okay now I get the different with 'out of' and 'with' I guess. 'out of' is only with majorly only paper and on the other hand 'with' is with paper and other stuff?

Comment: Then yeah this would be a bad quiz.

Comment: @341464: Teachers frequently give fill-in-the-blank tests that ask for as many words as there are blanks, no more, no fewer. One blank probably means one word; you gave two. They also frequently give tests only on what their lessons covered. There are many ways to fill in that blank: _with, from, out of, using, by folding, with glue and, with staples and, with tape and, etc._ All those options are correct English, but probably your teacher taught you only _with_, so that's what you should've put in the blank. You must figure out what your teacher expects & give it to her

Comment: Make of - build using almost only paper. Make out of - carve out of a massive block of paper. Make with - use paper in making it, but not as the only component. Make from - use paper, but the final result doesn't appear like paper (say, it's cinderblock created from burnt paper.)

Comment: @Bill, I hope your answer is a little tongue-in-cheek.  Please don't be encouraging a student to conform without question to implicit rules.  Student 341464, you could start by debating this politely with your teacher; he or she may be impressed by your imagination and independence and put more thought into future tests (hopefully not just buying them in).  If s/he isn't that bright and imaginative, learn to give him/her what is required but never forget that these things should be questioned!

Comment: @BillFranke I absolutely **abhor** when that happens. Especially at times like this, when the alternate answer is perfectly valid. Tests should assess your knowledge of English, not your knowledge of what was covered in lecture last week. Sounds like a really lousy quiz.

Comment: "from" and plain "of" are also in use here.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83256/made-in-made-of-or-made-with

Comment: @coleopterist: Westerners, especially Americans, are such individualists. They think that everyone thinks, feels, lives the way they do. In Asia & in other parts of the world, that just ain't so. Argue with your teacher in Asia, & you get put on a shit-list. The rule here is memorize & regurgitate. Teachers & students are overworked. Students sit, listen, write class notes, memorize, don't ask questions, & care about test scores because their parents do. Understanding is secondary or tertiary. Make your teacher look bad & lose face, & you have to find a new school. I'm easy. No face to lose.

Comment: @Carlo_R.these questions are **nothing** alike.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Bill can make a doghouse out of paper.

This is completely correct, and means that the product will be a paper doghouse.

> Bill can make a doghouse with paper.

This sounds peculiar, but I would understand it as a dog house where paper has been used instead of something else, or maybe a doghouse that has paper parts but is mostly made of another material.

Similarly

> I made the pancakes out of rice flour

implies you made rice flour pancakes, but

> I made the pancakes with rice flour

means that you could have used rice flour and wheat flour together.

Comment: The last example is more understandable than the doghouse one

Answer (score 16):

Your teacher writes bad quiz questions, unless there were some very careful specifications added that would disqualify your answer and require the allegedly "correct" one.  Teachers who write questions which they think have obviously correct answers have poor imaginations, penalise students with good imaginations and instil bad habits in the more impressionable students.

Both answers are good English; the meaning is almost identical.  You could argue that construction *out of* paper implies that paper is the principal component, where construction *with* paper does not, but I cannot see how that is relevant.

Were there any extra rules or guidelines attached to the quiz?  Did it specify single-word answers? If not, not only is your answer valid but a case might be argued for many others.

> Bill can make a doghouse *lined with* paper.  That's cool

Well, lining it with fur would be insanitary.

> Bill can make a doghouse *into* paper.  That's cool.

His dad built him a miniature wood-pulping machine in the back garden.

Oh, I dislike unimaginative teachers who abuse their god-like position to make such arbitrary and indefensible judgements.

Thinking about it some more, *with* doesn't even directly imply that the item specified is a component; *with*, in this case, is equivalent to *using* and it is up to the reader to infer, from context, whether the item is an ingredient or a tool.

> Bill made a pyramid with cardboard, scissors and tape; his teacher had told him it would be good for sharpening razor blades.

Which is another distinction between *with* and *out of* but still doesn't justify your teacher's ruling.

Comment: >Were there any extra rules or guidelines attached to the quiz? ||||Not so sure, there's only 1 space, but it didn't specify that in the question so I don't think so. And well what's funny is that the quizzes are from a company instead of teacher herself.

Comment: +1, especially for the *possibility* of a subtle distinction based on principal component; but in US *insanitary*, while correct would be puzzling, since it's rare compared to *unsanitary*.

Comment: Student 341464, I hope the fact that the quiz was bought in only reflects pressure of time on your teacher (and not low imagination or intellect).

Comment: To *make a doghouse **into** paper* is gibberish.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: no, it is not.  It simply requires explanation, which I provided.  It's every bit as good English (and as logical, if you have a miniature wood-pulper) as making paper *out of* a doghouse (although I wouldn't recommend it as an exam answer unless there's plenty of space to explain).  Are you Student 341464's teacher?  Or is this just some more of your "inadvertent carelessness"?

Comment: Was this quiz bought from a paper doghouse manufacturing company? That's the only reason I could imagine why this ill-thought out example was ever used.

Comment: @FumbleFingers haha, you're just like the teacher who graded this quiz.

Comment: We would probably say *turn a doghouse into paper*, rather than *make a doghouse into paper*, but I can't work out why that should be the case.

Comment: @Lunivore: probably because it requires the decomposition and reconstitution of the original material.  *turn into* better conveys the sense of that.

Comment: @phoenixheart6,itsbruce: Maybe there's a regional/dialectal factor involved here. Grammatically (and at a pinch, semantically) I accept you could ***turn** a doghouse into paper*. But idiomatically (and probably grammatically) where I come from (SE UK) you can't use *make* in such a construction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ohh I see your point. I think that is a regional thing. "Make into" is definitely acceptable from my understanding of English (American).

Comment: @phoenixheart6: NGrams claims 13,200 instances of, for example, [turn water into wine](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+water+into+wine%2Cturn+water+into+wine&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), but only 157 for ***make** water into wine*. I'd hazard a guess that if the second one sounds just as good as the first to you, it's probably a regional variation. If you agree with me that the first is far more "normal/natural", you're probably just more tolerant of the unusual variation.

Comment: I don't think that is a valid comparison.  You're comparing transmutation with construction and they are not the same.

Answer (score 14):

One implies materials, while the other implies tools.  Consider the following:

> Bill can make a doghouse out of wood.

vs.:

> Bill can make a doghouse with a hammer.

In these cases, there's a clear difference.  You wouldn't make a doghouse **out of** a hammer, and it's still kind of awkward to say you could make a doghouse **with** wood (though not as bad as the other case).

Comment: Your answer makes it sound like _out of_ is a **better** answer than _with_.

Comment: @J.R.: I think it is.  Unless the original test were to specify that it should be one word.  In which case, I'd say another alternative would be **from**.